# Eigen array is confused for OpenGL

Tags: arrays, opengl, graphics, eigen

Unexpected error for me. I wrote this code:

```
Eigen::Array <GLfloat, NumVertices, 2> vertices;
vertices(0, 0) = 0.90f; vertices(0, 1) = 0.90f;
vertices(1, 0) = 0.90f; vertices(1, 1) = -0.90f;
vertices(2, 0) = -0.90f; vertices(2, 1) = -0.90f;

glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
    vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And I see this:[image]
Why? How correctly use Eigen array for OpenGL?

What I think:
0,0 = x1   0,1 = y1
1,0 = x2   1,1 = y2
2,0 = x3   2,1 = y3
But drawed this:
1,1 = x1   2,1 = y1
2,0 = x2   0,1 = y2
0,0 = x3   1,0 = y3

Comment: What I think:
0,0 = x1   0,1 = y1
1,0 = x2   1,1 = y2
2,0 = x3   2,1 = y3
But drawed this:
1,1 = x1   2,1 = y1
2,0 = x2   0,1 = y2
0,0 = x3   1,0 = y3

Comment: Just curious but which IDE and/or Theme do you use, it looks great!

Comment: @Vallentin I think it's Visual Studio's slightly modified Dark Theme. You can achieve even more eye candies with [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) and [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) code highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the elements of an `Eigen::Array` are stored column major. So you have two options:

Use column 2D vectors:

```
Eigen::Array<float, 2, NumVertices> vertices;
```

or request for a row-major storage layout:

```
Eigen::Array<float, NumVertices, 2, Eigen::RowMajor> vertices;
```

Moreover, in general the number of vertices is not known at compile time, or it is rather large. In these cases, use `Eigen::Dynamic` instead of `NumVertices`:

```
Eigen::Array<float, 2, Eigen::Dynamic> vertices(2, num_vertices);
```